# How to define a recursive function which will square a positive integer

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program that creates a recursive function which will square a positive integer using this occurrence: x^2 = (x-1)^2 + 2x - 1. I thought I had something going, I typed in 2 and 4 was printed, however, once I started typing in other numbers such as 5, the value that was returned was 11 instead of the 25 I wanted. I am new to recursion and just wanted to write a simple program but it's clear I'm not comprehending the math portion, I could be wrong and my whole program is off but I think I have a fairly ok understanding on the main foundation of recursion. Any suggestions that could help me understand this better? Thank you!

I haven't done much with the base condition because I'm not sure what to do with it, but in the else statement, I've typed in different algorithms I thought would work such as sq(sqrt(x-1)) + (2*x) - 1; but that returned 13 when I typed in 5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int sq(int x) {

    if (x <= 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (sqrt(x-1)) + (2*x) - 1;
 }

int main() {
    int squarenum;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> squarenum;
    cout <<"Square of number: " <<  sq(squarenum) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program has to create a recursive function which will square a positive integer using this occurrence: x^2 = (x-1)^2 + 2x - 1.

So when I typed in 5, the output should be the 25, which is 5 squared, but instead, 11 is returned.

Comment: `sqrt` is square root and not square

Comment: The function you're looking for is `pow().` And there's no recursion you are using BTW.

Comment: The function `pow` returns a floating point value.  You may incur some loss of precision when converting from float to integer to float.

Comment: BTW, a more efficient method to square a number is: `x  * x`.  No function calls, load a register, use multiplication processor instruction.

Comment: You could also try: ` x^2 = (x + 1) * (x - 1);`  Note that this doesn't involve any square root functions and may give more accurate results.  I still believe you should use `x * x` instead.  This form may be more efficient than the simplified version.

Comment: So, why do you need recursion?  The equation doesn't involve recursion.

Comment: This is a typo :  `sqrt` should be `sq`.

Answer (score 3):

You must, of course, actually make the recursive call.

```
inline constexpr unsigned recursive_square(unsigned x)
{
    return x <= 1? x : recursive_square(x-1) + x+x - 1;
}
```

Comment: You need to make a recursive call in your recursive function? It's a world gone mad =P

Comment: @Walter he was being sarcastic.

Answer (score 2):

You've used `sqrt` instead of your function `sq`, this worked by chance when you entered 2 as `sqrt(2-1) = (2-1)^2 = 1`.

So changing your line `return (sqrt(x-1)) + (2*x) - 1;` to `return ((sq(x-1)) + (2*x) - 1);`

Should fix your problem! This solution will stick with your idea of making a recursive function but also solve the problem.